# Id always invalid

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I made a Blog page and I wanted to add comments to my blog page. I created a model and controller named `BlogComment` and I opened a `Create` action form belonging to `BlogComment` on my `Blog` page.

I get RefId invalid and attempt value = "" when I post the form, I would appreciate it if you could help.

This is my HTML markup:

```html
<form asp-area="onepoint" asp-controller="BlogComments" asp-action="Create">
    <div hidden>
        <input name="RefId" id="RefId" type="number" hidden>
        <input name="BlogId" id="BlogId" type="number" hidden>
        <input name="BlogCommentApproved" id="BlogCommentApproved" type="checkbox" value="true" hidden>
        <input name="BlogCommentApprovedById" id="BlogCommentApprovedById" type="number" hidden>
        <input name="BlogCommentApproveDate" id="BlogCommentApproveDate" type="datetime" hidden>
        <input name="CommentCreateDate" id="CommentCreateDate" type="datetime" hidden>
    </div>
    <div class="row">

        <div class="col-md-9">
            <div class="form-group">
                <textarea class="form-control" name="CommentContent" id="CommentContent" rows="5" placeholder="Yorumunuz..."></textarea>
            </div>

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <input class="form-control" name="Fullname" id="Fullname" type="text" placeholder="Ad Soyad">
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <input class="form-control" name="Email" id="Email" type="text" placeholder="E-Posta">
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <input id="SendFeedbackBlog" onclick="SendMessage()" type="submit" class="button-62" value="@localizer["Yorum Gönder"]" style="float:right">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3"></div>
    </div>
</form>
```

This is my `BlogComment` class:

```cs
/// <summary>
/// Referans Numarası
/// </summary>
[Key]
[Column(TypeName = "int")]
public int RefId { get; set; }

/// <summary>
/// Blog Id
/// </summary>
public int? BlogId { get; set; }
[ForeignKey("BlogId")]
public virtual Blog Blog { get; set; }
/// <summary>
/// Blog Yorumu Onayla
/// </summary>
public bool BlogCommentApproved { get; set; }

/// <summary>
/// Yorumu Onaylayan Kullanıcı Id'si
/// </summary>
public int? BlogCommentApprovedById { get; set; }
[ForeignKey("BlogApprovedById")]
public virtual User ApprovedBy { get; set; }

/// <summary>
/// Blog Yorumu Onay Tarihi
/// </summary>
public DateTime? BlogCommentApproveDate { get; set; }

/// <summary>
/// Yorumun Yazıldığı Tarih
/// </summary>
public DateTime? CommentCreateDate { get; set; }
/// <summary>
/// Yorum Yazanın İsim ve Soyismi
/// </summary>
public string Fullname { get; set; }

/// <summary>
/// Yorum Yazanın E-mail Adresi
/// </summary>
public string Email { get; set; }

/// <summary>
/// Yazılan Yorum
/// </summary>
public string CommentContent { get; set; }
```

And this is my `BlogCommentController`:

```cs
public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("RefId,BlogId,BlogCommentApproved,BlogCommentApprovedById,BlogCommentApproveDate,CommentCreateDate,Fullname,Email,CommentContent")] BlogComment blogComment)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        _context.Add(blogComment);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
    }
    ViewData["BlogId"] = new SelectList(_context.Blogs, "RefId", "RefId", blogComment.BlogId);
    return View(blogComment);
}
```

Comment: Have you added a break point and checked where you got the error when you debug? Is it caused by EFCore?

Comment: Not error the value  of RefId always "" and invalid i tried to remove hidden an type hidden to but still i get RefId invalid and attempt value=""

Comment: Could you show  SendMessage() function?

Comment: it just creates alert and says Message send

Comment: You you mean you always get the ModelState error RefId  is invalid ,are you passing a model to your blog page,and you want to keep the value you passed to it?(you didn't set the hidden input box with a default value,but you bind the property,it would alwasy null/default value ), a bit confusing

Comment: Idea came to my mind. Even if I don't create an input or give a value for the RefId field, since I sent it to the Create function, I thought that the RefId should increase automatically as long as Create is running, since it is a [Key], and it did.  so it solved thank you for help

Answer (score 2):

I tried with your codes and got the ModelState error:
[image]

Then I setted the input box with a default value 0

```
<input name="RefId" id="RefId" type="number" value="0" hidden>
```

the error disappeared
[image]
It seems a ModelBidng error

If you still got the same ModelState error,this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/validation?view=aspnetcore-6.0#non-nullable-reference-types-and-the-required-attribute) may help

Comment: and if you want to pass a model to your view and set your input box default vlaue   with it,you need to bind the data with asp-for="Someproperty of the model"

Comment: After reading your comment, an idea came to my mind. Even if I don't create an input or give a value for the RefId field, since I sent it to the Create function, I thought that the RefId should increase automatically as long as Create is running, since it is a [Key], and it did.